# Null pointer exception in pagefactory declaration for ios driver used when i use @iOSXCUITFindBy for java client 7.3.0 with selenium 3.141.59

Tags: ios, selenium, appium

What should be the page factory declaration when i use @iOSXCUITFindBy

I get null pointer exception

I use java client 7.3.0 and selenium 3.141.59

My current code is

public class IOSPageFactory {

```
public IOSPageFactory(IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver) {
        regBase.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), IOSPageFactory.class);

}

@iOSXCUITFindBy  (xpath = "//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='SIGN IN']")
public static WebElement YellowSignIn1;
```

Comment: Did you try with @ FindBy instead of @ iOSXCUITFindBy? I have used @ FindBy and it worked for me.

Comment: Try using this for PageFactory initialization.
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

Comment: I tried using @FindBy instead of @ iOSXCUITFindBy. But it did not worked for me. I defined  regBase.capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "XCUITest"); Hence i need to use @ iOSXCUITFindBy to declare the elements. Also i get java.lang.instantiationexception when i use PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

Comment: @ FindBy  with PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); works for me when i execute script for web application. but it does not work for IOS app where i locate elements using Appium inspector

Comment: Sre, when you run your program is your app getting launched?

Comment: Can you please share your appium launcher code and how you would be initialising this IOSPageFactory class?

Comment: added launch and initialization code below-

Comment: Did you check whether the driver object not null?

Comment: Driver object is not null because, i am able to run the script when i dont declare the elements using @ iOSXCUITFindBy. instead i declared it as "WebElement account = driver.findElement(By.xpath......" inside each methods where it works. But i am trying to declare them outside the method using @ iOSXCUITFindBy and i get null pointer exception only for this. https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1268 - as per this link i found the problem is with @ iOSXCUITFindBy and Appiumfiledecorator combination. i am looking for other alternative

Answer (score 0):

```
            final String URL_STRING = "http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"; 
            regBase.url = new URL(URL_STRING);

            regBase.capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            regBase.capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "***");
            regBase.capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "*******");
            regBase.capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
            regBase.capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "12.4");

            regBase.capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/*******");

            regBase.capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, true);
            regBase.capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "XCUITest");
            regBase.capabilities.setCapability("useNewWDA", true);
            regBase.capabilities.setCapability("xcodeOrgId", "*******");
            regBase.capabilities.setCapability("xcodeSigningId", "iPhone Developer");
            regBase.capabilities.setCapability("agentPath", "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj");
            regBase.capabilities.setCapability("bootstrapPath", "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent");
            regBase.capabilities.setCapability("updatedWDABundleId", "*********");
            regBase.capabilities.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_ACCEPT_ALERTS, false); // True will auto accept

            regBase.iosDriver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(regBase.url, regBase.capabilities);
            regBase.iosDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
```

//Initializing ios page factory :

```
            import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver; import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement;

            public class IOSPageFactory {

            public IOSPageFactory(IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver) {
                    this.driver = driver;
                    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);

            }


            @iOSXCUITFindBy  (xpath = "//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='SIGN IN']")
            public static WebElement YellowSignIn1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Driver type has to be an AppiumDriver.

```
public IOSPageFactory(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);

}
```